# How can i check my android device support wifi direct?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I am working with android wifi direct demo application. After installation in my device I noticed that it is not working as expected.

I am confused, does my device support wifi direct or special hardware feature required for wifi direct? My device is local walton brand and API level 16. After reading android documentation i know that Wi-Fi Direct added in API level 14 doesn't need a wireless access point.

My other question is if in a place where no wifi zone is created using wifi direct two or more device  communicate with each other. in summing my problem, i need to know if my device not support wifi direct what i do to run wifi demo. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

you should check in this way, because some devices do not support WiFi direct but still keep the WifiP2pManager code in framework.

```
private boolean isWifiDirectSupported(Context ctx) {
    PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
    FeatureInfo[] features = pm.getSystemAvailableFeatures();
    for (FeatureInfo info : features) {
        if (info != null && info.name != null && info.name.equalsIgnoreCase("android.hardware.wifi.direct")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [StoneLam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26860028/423105), which is probably the most robust, a quicker-and-dirtier method would be to go ahead and call [WifiP2pManager.discoverPeers()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#discoverPeers(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel,%20android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener)) as you would if WiFi Direct were supported. The latter takes an `ActionListener` with an `onFailure()` callback. The failure reason passed to [onFailure(int reason)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.html#onFailure(int)) can be [P2P_UNSUPPORTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#P2P_UNSUPPORTED), which would answer your question: the device doesn't support WiFi Direct.

A call to `onSuccess()` would mean the device **does** support WiFi Direct. A call to `onFailure()` with other failure reasons would probably be inconclusive as to the device's capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Above API 21 you can directly use `isP2pSupported ()` from WifiManager class.
For lower Api's you can use PackageManager class,

```
if(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.wifi.direct"))

//Wifi direct available
```

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.0 and later support Wi-Fi Direct. However, some of 4.x devices does not support Wi-Fi Direct because of it's WiFi driver

you can check your device using the code below

```
mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess() {
                //onSuccess
          }
          @Override
          public void onFailure(int reason) {
                //onFailure
          }
});
```

If your device support Wi-Fi Direct, `onSuccess` will be called after a moment. Otherwise, `onFailure` will be called.

Comment: Really? Surely you can get `onFailure()` called if the device supports WiFi Direct but WiFi is turned off, for example. So this method doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Checking if Wifi P2P is supported:

- In code: If you cannot get the system service, it's not supported

  ```
  mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
  ```
- Without code: Check whether the option is in the Settings app (Under Wifi)

As per your second question: yes, devices connected via wifi direct communicate without any existing wifi network.

Comment: The emulator shouldn't support P2P, but it's not returning null for me when I check mManager.