# Android WiFi Direct P2P Connection always fails

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p, miracast

I try to connect 2 Android devices via WiFi Direct so that I could use Miracast sometime but always get the same error.
Im working 3 days on that now but can't figure out, why this isnt working.

My logcat error:

```
I/wpa_supplicant( 4244): p2p0: P2P-FIND-STOPPED 
D/myOnda  ( 4533): onReceive action:android.net.wifi.p2p.DISCOVERY_STATE_CHANGE
D/myOnda  ( 4533): Discovery state changed: 1 ->1:stop, 2:start
I/ethernet( 3755): event: NEWLINK(16), flags=0X1002
I/ethernet( 3755): flags: BC MC
I/ethernet( 3755): poll state :(null):17:
I/wpa_supplicant( 4244): p2p0: Failed to start AP functionality
V/EthernetStateTracker( 3755): report new state DISCONNECTED on dev (null) current=null
```

Ok it says "Failed to start AP functionality" but I just don't know how and where to solve that.

I try that connection 1 time with a Samsung Note Pro and 1 time with a Nexus 4 and it's always the same.

Another curious part is that the mac is always different from the original (found that here too).

Comment: Not sure of the answer, but I am curious as I'll soon be undertaking the same in my project. There is an SO question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284506/how-to-enable-wifi-direct-and-wlan-through-wpa-supplicant) with comments that end in suggesting that the user check to make sure that the device's firmware actually supports wi-fi direct. There's code for that check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828487/how-can-i-check-my-android-device-support-wifi-direct

Comment: the firmware and android os are ok.
test an older miracast app from 2013 and suddenly it worked perfect.
Im still trying to figure out the differences.